# How do I bypass TCP and UDP filters (all ports for TCP and UDP are blocked)

Tags: authentication, vpn, filtering

I really want to play online games that use TCP/UDP, but the protocol is blocked. I can't use any VPN. I can use Tor and Psiphon, but they don't tunnel TCP and UDP (unless I use VPN mode but that doesn't work at school).

Anyone know any way to bypass the TCP /UDP PROTOCOL filter? My school is crazy on their Sophos Firewall. I tried SSTP too, but no luck. Their filter makes me go insane at school. I can't study because of it.
Please don't reply saying stuff like "you go to school to study, not play games" and "there are offline games".
I want to play games at lunch and recess, not during class.

Comment: if **all** ports for TCP and UDP are blocked, how do you connect to Internet at school at all? Via proxy? Which protocols can you use?

Comment: You want to bypass firewalls because you need to play at school? No, don't do that. You will end up not studying enough, having bad grades, and can be suspended for "hacking the school." That will not be good for your future.